# Is it possible to retrieve dependency injected arguments in another class?

Tags: magento2, dependency-injection, di, construct

Is it possible to retrieve dependency injected arguments in another class?

For example, we have a class `Vendor\Module\Block\Autocomplete`.

```
// app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Autocomplete.php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

class Autocomplete {
    
    protected $_data = [];
    
    public function __construct(array $data){
        $this->_data = $data;
    }
    public function getRendererList(){
        return $this->_data['rendererList'];
    }
}
```

The following dependency injection happens to that class;

```
<!-- app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml -->
<type name="Vendor\Module\Block\Autocomplete">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="rendererList" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="renderer_x" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="title" xsi:type="string">News</item>
                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/autocomplete/renderer_x</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Now I want to reuse the `rendererList` in another class (for example `Vendor\Module\Block\Widget\Autocomplete`) but the class can't extend from `Vendor\Module\Block\Autocomplete` since it is already extending from another class.

```
// app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Widget/Autocomplete.php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Widget;

class Autocomplete extends AbstractWidget {
    
    protected $_data = [];
    
    public function __construct(array $data){
        $this->_data = $data;
    }
    public function getRendererList(){
        return $this->_data['rendererList'];
    }
}
```

**The following is not working, because the data argument doesn't get populated**

```
// app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Widget/Autocomplete.php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Widget;

class Autocomplete extends AbstractWidget {
    
    protected $_autocomplete;
    
    public function __construct(Vendor\Module\Block\Autocomplete $autocomplete){
        $this->_autocomplete = $autocomplete;
    }
    public function getRendererList(){
        return $this->_autocomplete->getRendererList();
    }
}
```